# keras variable-length input for LSTM (merge two Embedding)

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to write a lstm with two Embedding Layers as input.

Because I have two different word2vec models, I think present one sentence can as two embeddings would be better.

The flow is 
`[inputs_1, inputs_2] ->  [embeddings_1, embeddings_2] - > lstm`

I write below test code according to some github keras issues.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# @Author: mithril

from __future__ import unicode_literals, print_function, absolute_import, division

import multiprocessing

import numpy as np
from keras import initializers
from keras.layers import Embedding, LSTM, Input, Dense, Concatenate, Reshape
from keras.layers import concatenate # in functional api
from keras.optimizers import Adagrad
from keras.models import Sequential, Model

class CONFIG:
    embedding_dim = 100
    squence_legth = 32
    batch_size = 32
    steps_per_epoch= 1000
    validation_steps= 10
    epochs = 500

# np.random.random_sample
char_weights = np.random.rand(100, CONFIG.embedding_dim)

pinyin_weights = np.random.rand(10, CONFIG.embedding_dim)

def my2em_lstm():

    inputs_1 = Input(shape=(CONFIG.embedding_dim,))
    inputs_2 = Input(shape=(CONFIG.embedding_dim,))

    char_em = Embedding(
        output_dim = char_weights.shape[1],
        input_dim = char_weights.shape[0], # vocab_size
        mask_zero = True,
        weights = [char_weights],
    )(inputs_1)

    pinyin_em = Embedding(
        output_dim = pinyin_weights.shape[1],
        input_dim = pinyin_weights.shape[0], # vocab_size
        mask_zero = True,
        weights = [pinyin_weights],
    )(inputs_2)

    em = concatenate([char_em, pinyin_em])

    x = LSTM(128, activation='sigmoid', inner_activation='hard_sigmoid')(em)

    x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
    #x = Dropout(CONFIG.amount_of_dropout)(x)

    main_out = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)

    model = Model(inputs=[inputs_1, inputs_2], outputs=main_out)

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy',
               metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model


def input_generator(batch_size):

    while True:
        l = np.random.randint(2,30)
        inputs_1 = []
        inputs_2 = []
        y = []
        for i in range(batch_size):
            # add replace=False  to disable replace

            inputs_1.append(char_weights[np.random.choice(char_weights.shape[0], l)])
            inputs_2.append(pinyin_weights[np.random.choice(pinyin_weights.shape[0], l)])

            y.append(i%2)

        yield [np.concatenate(inputs_1), np.concatenate(inputs_2)], y

model = my2em_lstm()

model.fit_generator(input_generator(32), 
                    steps_per_epoch=CONFIG.steps_per_epoch,
                    epochs=CONFIG.epochs,
                    verbose=1, 
                    # callbacks=[ON_EPOCH_END_CALLBACK, ], 
                    validation_data=input_generator(32),
                    validation_steps=CONFIG.validation_steps,
                    use_multiprocessing=True, #Multiple generators are instantiated only when 
                    workers=multiprocessing.cpu_count(),
                    initial_epoch=0)
```

But I got error

```
Epoch 1/500                                                                                                  
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                           
  File "lstm.py", line 150, in <module>                                                                      
    initial_epoch=0)                                                                                         
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 87, in wrapper              
    return func(*args, **kwargs)                                                                             
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2042, in fit_generator        
    class_weight=class_weight)                                                                               
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1756, in train_on_batch       
    check_batch_axis=True)                                                                                   
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1390, in _standardize_user_dat
a                                                                                                            
    _check_array_lengths(x, y, sample_weights)                                                               
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 241, in _check_array_lengths  
    'and ' + str(list(set_y)[0]) + ' target samples.')                                                       
ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 768 input samples and
 32 target samples.
```

Here, I knew a problem is `l = np.random.randint(2,30)` which is used for simulation of variable-length sentence.
I think this error is another one, I guess it is by both  `x` and `y` 's shape, but I can't figure it out